# MySQLi insert query not reading values from form, inserting blank data

Tags: php, mysql

now the problem I am having is that the data submitted from the form is not being inserted into the database.
My code is inserting a record into the users table, but only the static value "active" is being inserted. Nothing from the form fields is being included, and is blank.

connection.php is the initial database connection file, which is working as its inserting a row albeit blank (with exception of the acc_active set to active hardcoded). Search.php is not important

Here is my code.

```
<?php
        require "connection.php";
        require "search.php";
        $var_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
        $var_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
        $var_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);

        if (isset($_GET['reg'])){
                if ($_GET['reg']=='1'){
                        $verify         =       mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM users WHERE username = '$var_username'");
                        $result         =       mysqli_fetch_array($verify);
                        if($result[0]==1){
                                $error_msg      =       "Username exists";
                        }else{
                                $query          =       "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, acc_active)VALUES('$var_username','$var_password','$var_email','active')";
                                if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
                                echo "success";
                                }else{
                                echo "failed". $sql ."<br>". mysqli_error($conn);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And here is the html form, this is inside a

```
 <form method="post" action="/rail/register.php?reg=1" style="text-align:center">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Username..." name="username" />
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email..." name="email" />
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." name="password" />
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password..." name="password-confirm" />

                           <a href="/rail/login">Return / Cancel</a>
                           <input type="submit" name="Register" value="Register" />
                    </form>
```

So I am reloading the page with value reg=1 to indicate an insert, 
I am verifying that there are no other records with that username,
I am then running insert query

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Ive left the above code very basic at this stage, Ill do error messages, and verification that password/confirm password fields match etc. as well as hashing once basic setup is complete.

Comment: echo your variables after mysqli_real_escape_string()..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
        require "connection.php";
        require "search.php";
        // You can remove the need to escape your strings by using prepared statements.
```

The check with REG is unnecessary. Best to remove it.

```
if(isset($_POST['Register'])){

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT null FROM users WHERE username = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->fetch()){
$error = "Username exists.";
}
else{
$error = "";
}
$stmt->close();

if($error == ""){
$param = "Active";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, acc_active) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'], $param);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();    
}
else
{
  echo $error;
}

}
```

Assuming your form is on the same page, you can simply remove the action you add previous. Else you can keep it, but remove the REG.

```
 <form method="post" action="" style="text-align: center">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Username..." name="username" >
       <input type="text" placeholder="Email..." name="email" />
       <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." name="password">
       <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password..." name="password-confirm">

       <a href="/rail/login">Return / Cancel</a>
       <input type="submit" name="Register" value="Register">
  </form>
```

Comment: How would I amend this code so that I can check email address for duplicates as well? Duplicate the code block but checking email instead of username? Thanks

Comment: @trainmania100 You could quickly do this two ways: the 1st way is copy the top code block (as you described in your question), but replace $_POST['username'] with $_POST['email'] (no other changes needed. The 2nd way is you could amend the query in the first code block to say, "SELECT null FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? " and then change your bound parameters to bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['email']);

If you do it the second way, remember to change your error message to something like, "Duplicate found."

Answer (score 0):

Please use POST method , you are using get

Also you can write your code in a faster way:

```
if (isset($_POST['reg']) && $_POST['reg']=='1'){
```

instead of:

```
 if (isset($_GET['reg'])){
                if ($_GET['reg']=='1'){
```

Comment: reg is the url parameter not the form

Comment: if `reg` wouldn't be in `$_GET`, a row with a static value `active` would *not* be inserted.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
    $var_username = $_POST['username'];
```

instead of

```
    $var_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
```

You can use mysqli_real_escape_string() while making the query;

Comment: Unfortunately that did not make any difference, sorry

Comment: Did you try a print_r($_POST)?

Comment: Echo  the $query value and exit it. You can see what you are getting in Insert query